# Define the same logger level for two python modules

Tags: python, logging, module

EDIT: This work perfectly. The problem was in other part of the code.

Y have two modules: test.py and dscc.py, the first one has the following code:

```
# test.py
from logging import getLogger, basicConfig

logger = getLogger(__name__)

def main(level='INFO') -> None:
    basicConfig(level=level)
    
    logger.info('This is a test')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main('WARNING')
```

And the other one call this with the following code:

```
# dscc.py
from my_package import test


def main() -> None:
    """ Main function. """
    test.main('WARNING')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

That means, the second script calls the first one. The question is that the log level is defined correctly when I execute test.py directly but basicConfig() does nothing when I execute dscc. Does someone know how to solve the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of `if __name__ == '__main__':` is to run the this code only when the script is run as a top-level. If you want to run some piece even on import, then don't put in inside such clause.
As it is right now, `basicConfig` never happens when you import `test.py`

Comment: The line with `basicConfig()` is executing because I call the test main inside `dscc.main()` with the code `parser.args.func(parser.args)`. I've checked and those lines are executing.

Comment: Maybe, the example code is too complex. I'm going to simplify it.

Comment: Here is what I do in such case personally: I have a loggerSetup module that imports `logging` and does `basicConfig`. Then in each module I wanna use logging I do `from loggerSetup import logging`, `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)`

Comment: I think the problem is deeper I previously thought because I've just tested the simpler code and it was working perfectly. I think it is something related with the ArgumentParser. I need to put more code to explain it better.

Comment: About to use a common module to configure the logging module, I've already tried that and it is not working neither. I'm going to explain the problem better and improve my example of code.

Comment: I found the error and it was because I use basicConfig in other import as well. My error. Sorry for noise.